# Problema con Asterisk 11.6 format_wav_gsm.c: Unable to set our position

Tags: asterisk

Tengo un problema con mi instalación de Asterisk, algunas extensiones me arrojan el siguiente error:

> [Nov  9 09:09:29] WARNING[394][C-0000053f] format_wav_gsm.c: Unable to set our position

Tengo dos servidores Asterisk mas, con la misma configuración y no hay problemas, es en ese servidor que esta dando el problema.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede ser?

Comment: Por empezar es un `warning`, que tal vez puedas ignorar, por otro lado ¿Has visto esto: http://vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum/viewtopic.php?t=6210?